# How do you usually arrange a date? Sentence structure

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How do you usually arrange a date?

What would be more appropriate and natural:

- What about tomorrow/on Sunday at 5 near the Star Theater?
- How about tomorrow/on Sunday at 5 near the Star Theater?
- Let's meet tomorrow/on Sunday at 5 near the Star Theater?
- Let's meet near the Star Theater tomorrow/on Sunday at 5?

or nothing from that?

Thank you

Comment: Is your question about the natural order of the adverbials: _tomorrow | on Sunday | at 5 | near the Star Theater_? Or is it about the natural way to make a suggestion: _what about | how about | let's_?

Answer (score 1):

The first two feel more like negotiation, as if you're making a flexible suggestion or trying to change the time someone else suggested.

The latter two are more definitive (and should end with periods and not question marks).

They are all reasonably natural.

(That said, I think most people would just say "Sunday" and not "on Sunday".)